# What can we say about the inner product $\langle f(t),f'(t) \rangle$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose we have vector-valued function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $|f(t)|=1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

> What can we say about the inner product $\langle f(t), f'(t) \rangle$?

Since image of $f$ is a vector ($n$-tuple). Then $|f(t)|=1$ implies we are looking at all those points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose distance from $(0,\dots,0)$ is $1$. In other words, we are looking the point on the surface of unit sphere.

But, how this idea help in computing the inner product?

The notes I am reading says that answer is zero but I can not figure out how? I would be thankful if somebody can provide a little hint.

Comment: Can you check that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}|f(t)|^2 = 2\langle f(t), f'(t) \rangle? $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you. I got it. I did not know about this result. I have show that the equality hold by using the definition of derivative. Thanks again.

Comment: StammeringMathematician, sure you did, it's the product rule $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$. The product rule applies to anything bilinear, like multiplication or inner product. The proof is literally the same for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f|=1$ implies $\langle f,f\rangle=|f|^2=1$ and, as a consequence,
$$
\langle f,f\rangle'=2\langle f,f'\rangle=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f=(f_1,...,f_n)$. Then

$$\langle f,f'\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^nf_kf_k'=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n(f_k^2)'=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{k=1}^nf_k^2)'=\frac{1}{2}1'=0.$$