# Show $ \langle f(t), f'(t) \rangle = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble getting started on proving/disproving the following:

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $|f(t)| = 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then the scalar product $ \langle f(t), f'(t) \rangle = 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The same question (only for vector-valued functions) was asked and answered recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102196/what-can-we-say-about-the-inner-product-langle-ft-ft-rangle

Comment: I think we have $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n.$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102196/what-can-we-say-about-the-inner-product-langle-ft-ft-rangle/3102216#3102216

Comment: Hint: Differentiate the relation $$\langle f(t),f(t)\rangle=1$$